# writing/returning a HTML String to file to internal file directory android

Tags: android

Hi i have a string that contains html and css that i want to load into a WebView as a file. so i want to create a Directory on the internal storage i don't really want to store it on an SDCard as the file i'm saving contains important information. I then want to create a mFile.html not that directory. And the final step is then return the file to load into a WebView. Does anyone know how to do this?

heres what i have tried so far

```
public static void writeFileToDirectory(Context activityContext, String writableString,String folderName, String fileName){


    File myDir = activityContext.getFilesDir();

    try {
        File secondFile = new File(myDir + "/" + folderName + "/", fileName);
        if (secondFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
            secondFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(secondFile);

            fos.write(writableString.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        File secondInputFile = new File(myDir + "/html/", fileName);
        InputStream secondInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(secondInputFile));
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(secondInputStream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        r.close();
        secondInputStream.close();
        Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

File myDir = activityContext.getFilesDir();

try {
    File secondFile = new File(myDir + "/" + folderName);
       if(!secondFile.exists())
        {
           secondFile.mkdir();
         }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(secondFile.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileaName);

        fos.write(writableString.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```